# How to get multiple queries done in one single query

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make the following queries done in one single query and get the result just the way it is in below?

```
// Begining of January

$ob = mysql_query(" SELECT SUM(salary_amount) AS total FROM teacherexpense WHERE  month(disburse_date)='01' AND  year(disburse_date)='$year' ");
$nt = mysql_fetch_assoc($ob);
$salaryamount= $nt['total'];


$ob = mysql_query(" SELECT SUM(other_expense_amount) AS expenseamount FROM otherexpense WHERE month(other_expense_date)='01' AND year(other_expense_date)='$year'  ");
$nt = mysql_fetch_assoc($ob);
$expenseamount= $nt['expenseamount'];

$jk = mysql_query(" SELECT SUM(amountpaid) AS revenue FROM studentpayment1 WHERE month(received_date)='01' AND year(received_date)='$year' ");
$t = mysql_fetch_assoc($jk);
$revenue= $t['revenue'];

$ob = mysql_query(" SELECT SUM(other_earning_amount) AS otherearningamount FROM otherearning WHERE month(other_earning_date)='01' AND year(other_earning_date)='$year' ");
$nt = mysql_fetch_assoc($ob);
$otherearningamount= $nt['otherearningamount'];


$January= ($revenue+$otherearningamount)-($salaryamount+$expenseamount);
// End of January
```

Comment: You could use `UNION`, each row will represent different query.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff it in a Stored Procedure?
The database drivers for PHP won't let you run several queries separated with ; for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mysqli drivers instead of mysql?

Take a look at: [mysqli_multi_query](http://es.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

*Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.*

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'withdrawals' t, SUM( amount ) sum
FROM withdrawals
UNION
SELECT 'statement' t, SUM( amount ) sum
FROM statement
```

[image]

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $total[$row['t']] = $row['sum'];
}

echo $total['withdrawals']; # 100
echo $total['statement']; # 624.x
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MySQL UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) - but you'll have to iterate over the resultset, because in that case you will get 4 records instead of one/statement group